# Remove records from a dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, filter

I have a dataframe in Python 3 with 4 True/False variables. If all 4 of the variables are False, I want to remove the records from the dataframe.

I tried the following but it didn't work for me:

```
df.drop(df.loc[(df['1']==False) & (df['2']==False) & (df['3']==False) & (df['4']==False)])
```

If do what's inside the `df.drop` then I am able to isolate the records that I wish to remove:

```
df.loc[(df['1']==False) & (df['2']==False) & (df['3']==False) & (df['4']==False)]
```

I apologize, this is my first time using StackOverflow for help so please let me know if I need to provide more detail.

Comment: `1 2 3 4 5` exists in both.  If that is not a "record", you need to specify.  The problem description is ambiguous.  As it is, it feels like `grep -F -f ...` will do the job.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverflow. We do not help with homework questions. You might want to see resources for how to look up an item in df and how to delete an item in df and build your logic accordingly.

Comment: This isn't a homework problem this is a business problem.... i'm just using a general table to mask PHI; if what you're telling me is that my question is too rudimentary then I apologize, this website isn't the resource that I was told it is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted with the following:

```
df.loc[~((df.1==False) & (df.2==False) & (df.3==False) & (df.4==False))]
```

Sorry for not being more clear.